# How to generate json object from hive SQL table description?

Tags: json, hive, hiveql, hiveddl

I use `describe formatted table_name` to get the description of the table. I get following result. I want to convert this to json somehow. Any good approach for this? In other words, I want to get my sql table description as json. Not as a table like the one shown in following output.

[image: Output of desc formatted table_name]

The output which I want to get should look like :

```
{
    "columns" : {
        "id" : "int",
        "name": "string"
    },


    "partition_information": {
        "columns" : {
            "dt_temp" : "string"
        }
    },

    "Detailed table information" : {
        "Database" : "d1",
        "owner" : "root",
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        
    }
}
```

Is there any function or library that will do this for me? Right now, I'm doing this manually using python script, but it is very difficult and messy. I don't expect the exact same output that I mentioned, I'm looking for a way to parse this easily and meaningfully from some python script. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DESCRIBE EXTENDED can produce JSON (checked it works fine on Hive 2.1.1):

```
set hive.ddl.output.format=json;
desc extended table_name;
```

It produces output like this:

```
{"columns":[{"name":"id","type":"bigint","comment":"from deserializer"}, 
            {"name":"col1","type":"string","comment":"from deserializer"},
            ...
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but it is not giving me complete json object. I only get column names and their types, rest of the information is lost in the json object. Information including partitioning columns, input format is not received in json object.

Comment: @RuchitVithani In my hive 2.1.1 it returned "partitionKeysIterator" array, "inputFormat", "outputFormat"

Comment: @RuchitVithani DESC FORMATTED does not return partitionKeysIterator and Inputformat, but DESC EXTENDED works, please check you are using DESC EXTENDED

Comment: Is it possible to hit create table query from such json object?

Comment: @RuchitVithani Possible. Using JSONSerDe But All data is a single JSON object with nested structures and arrays. If you create is as is - then table will have single column and single row with complex type. And it is not convenient though it should be possible to explode arrays in SQL.  Everything in {} is a map<> or STRUCT<>, everything in [] is array. like this: JSON  struct< columns: array<struct<name: string, type: string, ...>,  ... >

Comment: @RuchitVithani Use JSONSerDe, and describe schema like in my previous comment, do not put all JSON into STRING . If you create single col with complex type then you will be able to easily access all nested structures and explode arrays.